# When do Golden Hats appear?

Tags: battleblock-theater

I've only seen one Golden Hat in several hours of play. Does the Golden Hat spawn more often in certain levels, in solo vs. co-op, or based on some other criteria? Are its spawn conditions completely random? How can I make them appear more often?

Comment: Alright, I have to ask... How is this game? I've been eyeing it for a little while now.

Comment: @Fluttershy: Totally worth it for local co-op

Comment: What about online co-op? I'm sort of lacking in people to play local co-op with.

Comment: @Fluttershy: You'll want to voice chat for the teamwork (could be frustrating to just gesticulate), but otherwise online's the same as local. Not as fun to play with randoms online, but with friends, yes. Same accessibility as _Castle Crashers_ in that regard. Definitely recommended

Answer (score 4):

**Golden Hat** spawn randomly.

> They spawn during Campaign and most Arena levels both in a random
>   location and at a random time.
>   There is no guarantee of finding a Golden Hat(...), although there is always a chance.

Comment: Please cite your source